# How do we use SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES with SHCreateDirectoryEx()?

Tags: c++, c, file, directory, directory-structure

My requirements are as follows:

1. Creation of a directory at a specified location.
2. Setting its attributes such that the folder is "READ ONLY". In other words, user accounts should not be able to create a folder/file inside this folder.

Now, I am able to create directory as follows:

```
SHCreateDirectoryEx( NULL, <path>.c_str(), NULL );
```

I would now like to set appropriate security attributes. Any help/code example would be appreciated.

Platform: Win7 (Lang: C++/C)

Comment: `SHCreateDirectoryEx` is irrelevant. You question is entirely about `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing  you'd do is create a `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` struct, and set it's members.

```
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES SecAttr;

SecAttr.size = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES); //Set size of structure
```

The next member is a type of `SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR` which actually contains all the data needed to manage security access to this object.

You cannot directly create this structure, as per [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa379561%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but you would use the functions provided in the documentation to create such a struct, set all it's necessary flags as required and then get a pointer to it to pass to `SecAttr`.

An example on how to create such a `SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR` struct can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa446595%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  In this example it's done for a registry key, but the principle is the same.

Essentially you're filling in an DACL ([Discretionary Security Access Control List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms721573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_security_discretionary_access_control_list_gly)) or SACL ([System Access Control List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms721625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_security_system_access_control_list_gly) with the right properties of what access (read/write/read-only) etc, you want the object to have.

Having filled out the entire `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` struct you can pass it to your `SHCreateDirectoryEx` function.